# How to save logs to database in AOP advice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I have a problem with saving logs (or any other information) in the database when using Spring AOP.

Here's the source of problems:

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Autowired
    private LogService logService;

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate+.*(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void logError(Exception ex) {
        Log log = new Log("Error!");
        logService.save(log);
    }
}
```

`logService` instance is a simple `@Service` class which calls `@Repository` methods internally. Nothing special. `Log` class is even simpler:) It contains only one variable (two if we include id):

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Log {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String message;

    //getters, setters, constructors, etc.
}
```

`LoggingAspect` works correctly. `@AfterThrowing` advice is called properly in case of any exceptions. But nothing is saved in db after calling `save` method.
When I try to call `getAll()` method instead of `save` everything works as expected. All data is loaded from the database.
This problem applies only to the `save` method.

I'll be grateful for any hints.

Edit: 
As I mentioned previously, the `@Service` and `@Repository` classes are very basic for now. And maybe it's worth adding that outside aspect class everything works perfectly. It is possible to save logs in the database. This issue occurs only with saving and only when used in all kinds of advices.
Service code added

```
@Service
public class LogService {

    @Autowired
    private LogRepository logRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Log> getAllLogs() {
        return logRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(Log log) {
        logRepository.save(log);
    }
}
```

Repository code added

```
@Repository
public interface LogRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Log> {
}
```

Comment: pls post the `LogService` code

Comment: @ThomasAndolf `LogService` code added

Comment: have you `@EnableJpaRepositories` ?

Comment: Nope but I use Spring Boot so I think it is enabled autmaitcally by auto configuration. And as I mentioned in my "edit" - everything works fine outside aspect class

Comment: and for reference `By default, CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional. For read operations, the transaction configuration readOnly flag is set to true. All others are configured with a plain @Transactional so that default transaction configuration applies. ` https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions

Comment: pls try removing the `@Configuration` on your aspect

Comment: ok. Tomorrow I will try to do it and let you know if anything has changed

Comment: @ThomasAndolf unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like transaction handling.

But more info would be good, **I can only guess here**. So few points to check, if you didn't already.

I guess you put @Transational on the Service or Repositoty, right? Also make sure you have Repository, Service in seperate classes as of the Spring default proxying mechanism.

Debug and add logging for jpa, hibernate and spring transaction.

Comment: `@Trasactional` is used on my Service class and of course Repository and Service are in a separate classes. I suppose it is some kind of transaction problem but I don't know how to resolve it yet. When I debug my code everything seems to be ok. For example `logRepository.save(log);` method returns saved entity (id value is set) but no changes in the database.
I also see that hibernate logs some inserts into db but still... no changes in the DB.
I will  try to enable all logs for jpa, hibernate, spring. I know it's very easy to fix, but I've spent three days on it and I've had enough

Comment: Service and Repository looks ok, so must be some missconfig or on the Aspüect handling. Can't help you there, sorry.

Comment: If nothing helps you could do the transaction manually:
UserTransaction utx = entityManager.getTransaction(); 

try { 
    utx.begin(); 
    businessLogic();
    utx.commit(); 
} catch(Exception ex) { 
    utx.rollback(); 
    throw ex; 
}

Comment: Why is thre @Component on your Aspejt config?

Comment: Chapter: "The Transactional Aspect" on https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional. This put me back to the "commit"-missing theory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a solution!
As I suspected it was a transaction problem. A new transaction has to be started regardless of any existing transaction. So one line (or rather transaction property) is missing in the `@Service` class

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void save(Log log) {
    logRepository.save(log);
}
```

Thank you to everyone who helped solve the problem.

Comment: I cannot resist a little remark: _"As I suspected"_? You didn't suspect anything or even mention transactions. It was user @R.S who mentioned that in his answer. So please be a gentleman and give the guy some credit instead of pretending to have solved this all by yourself.

Comment: I mentioned that I suspect problems with transactions, but I had no idea what exactly could be wrong - "I suppose it is some kind of transaction problem but I don't know how to resolve it yet.". But I agree that R.S answer was helpful so I voted up his post

Comment: That was your comment under R.S's answer, so he suggested it. You only confirmed later. It is always easy to claim the idea for yourself after someone else has mentioned it first.